# sql case statement with date values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date column in my database table.

```
SELECT sDestructionDate FROM tblDocumentHeader
```

below is the result of above query

[image]

I need to print empty for the date value '1991-01-01'

I expect a result set something like below.

[image]

I tried the below query but it still print that '1991-01-01' date.

```
SELECT CASE CONVERT(date,h.sDestructionDate,103) 
WHEN '01/01/1991' 
THEN '' 
ELSE CONVERT(date,h.sDestructionDate,103) END 
AS 'sDestructionDate'
FROM tblDocumentHeader h
```

I don't want to convert the result into varchar value. below query does gives me the result but i need to return it from date format.

```
SELECT CASE CONVERT(varchar,h.sDestructionDate,103) 
WHEN '01/01/1991' 
THEN '' 
ELSE convert(varchar,h.sDestructionDate,103) END 
AS 'sDestructionDate'
FROM tblDocumentHeader h
```

Comment: @Bohemian i need to try it but still i need to use the case statement right?

Comment: Is `sDestructionDate` a real date column, or a varchar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would first convert it to a null:

```
select
    case
        when h.sDestructionDate = '01/01/1991' then null
        else h.sDestructionDate
    end as sDestructionDate
from tblDocumentHeader h
```

Then look to your reporting tool to *present* a blank if the value is `null`

---

Mixing data with presentation is a mistake. This approach is simple and keeps the two concerns of *data* and *rendering* separate.

Comment: If sDestructionDate was a date field, the query would be: `WHEN CAST('1991-01-01' AS DATE) THEN null`